# wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'VENTAS_MAYOR'

Tags: oracle, plsql

I made a procedure called 'VENTAS_MAYOR' with a parameter 'FECHITA' type DATE

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE VENTAS_MAYOR (FECHITA IN DATE)

IS
V_FECHA DATE;
V_CANTIDAD NUMBER;
V_DESCRIPCION VARCHAR2(50);
BEGIN
SELECT 
A.FECHAEMISION_BOL,
B.CANTIDAD,
C.DESCRIPCION

INTO 
V_FECHA,
V_CANTIDAD,
V_DESCRIPCION

FROM BOLETA A JOIN DETALLE B ON (A.COD_BOLETA = B.COD_DETALLE)
      JOIN PRODUCTO C ON (B.COD_DETALLE = C.CODPRODUCTO)
WHERE A.FECHAEMISION_BOL = FECHITA
ORDER BY CANTIDAD DESC;

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(V_CANTIDAD || V_DESCRIPCION);
END VENTAS_MAYOR;
```

But when i am going to execute the function/procedure with a parameter i get that error...

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
EXECUTE VENTAS_MAYOR(05/2019);
```

I don't know why i'm getting this error , i'm using only a parameter.... !

Comment: You are not passing a date, you are passing the result of an arithmetic expression - one number (05) divided by another (2019).  You need to grasp the difference between strings, numbers, and dates. A DATE is an internal, binary structure.  What you used is just a character representation of a DATE. And worse, since you didn't enclose it in single quotes, oracle didn't even treat it as a string but as numbers.

Comment: `05/2019` is 0.002476473501734, not a date. Dates are written like this: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Literals.html#GUID-8F4B3F82-8821-4071-84D6-FBBA21C05AC1

Answer (score 1):

You are passing the `string` as a parameter but oracle is expecting a `date`.
You need to pass a `date` as follows:

```
VENTAS_MAYOR(date'2019-05-01');
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you need to pass input in date format. Correct way of calling this procedure is,

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
EXECUTE VENTAS_MAYOR(to_date('05/01/2019','mm/dd/yyyy');
```

Also, make sure datatype of `FECHAEMISION_BOL` column in `BOLETA` table. It should be `DATE` or `TIMESTAMP`. If not, you need to modify the WHERE condition as follows -

```
to_date(A.FECHAEMISION_BOL,'mm/dd/yyyy') = FECHITA
```